# Removing html tags (if present) and placing it before word in php

Tags: php, html, regex

There is user response which may contain some html tags. For example:

```
$text = "HE<b>llo wo</b>r<a>ld and</a> world"
```

I can replace the first world by *preg_replace* using the following

```
preg_replace('/\s[A-Za-z0-9\<\/\>]*\s/',' world ',$match);
```

But how to format it in the such a way

```
$text = "HE<b>llo </b>world<a> and</a> world"
```

i.e replace the html closing tags before the word and starting tags after the word where the word and tags would be dynamic.

Comment: If you say *replace the html starting tags after the word*, you cannot achieve what you need with `HE<b>llo`, the `b` tag will be moved with this requirement.

Comment: By the way that's what I want to implement.

Comment: But that means you want to get `HEllo<b> </b>world<a> and</a> world`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/IstPw9/1). Or do I miss anything?

Comment: Literally speaking, finding it very hard to understand your question !

Comment: Your answer is correct. But Sorry I cannot understant how it was generated specially the regexp, would you post your comment as answer with the regexp in it.